# How to properly remove func from ViewController swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, parsing, tableview

I'm quite tired because i feel there is simple solution but i can't find it for days! I'm trying to remove parseJSON() from ViewController so it looks better but it's not working when it's removed, yet it still parsing data. Inside ViewController this func works absolutely fine and showing tableView with parsed data. I tried to add reloadData() and it didn't help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5lgD.jpg - screenshots

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

private var companyModel: CompanyModel? 
private lazy var employeesTable: UITableView = { 
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return table
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseJSON()
    view.addSubview(employeesTable)
    employeesTable.frame = view.bounds
    employeesTable.delegate = self
    employeesTable.dataSource = self
}

private func parseJSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/1d1cb4ec-73db-4762-8c4b-0b8aa3cecd4c") else { return }
    do {
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        companyModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(CompanyModel.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

It's working as you can see on second screenshot

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager {
    
    var companyModel: CompanyModel?
    func parseJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/1d1cb4ec-73db-4762-8c4b-0b8aa3cecd4c") else { return }
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            companyModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(CompanyModel.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    private var companyModel: CompanyModel?
    private lazy var employeesTable: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        networkManager.parseJSON()
        view.addSubview(employeesTable)
        employeesTable.frame = view.bounds
        employeesTable.delegate = self
        employeesTable.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

but this one is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which companyModel are you/should you be using, the "private var companyModel" in MainViewController or the networkManager's companyModel? Why two of them?  - You don't show your table view data source methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two critical problems

First of all, I see you have two `companyModel` : first one in class `NetworkManager` and second in class `MainViewController` and both have no connection which each others. The reason table view shows data when you parse json in `MainViewController` because it connects to the `companyModel` in `MainViewController`. You must remove one of them.

Second, when you parse json from URL, you should make an asynchronous function for parse Json in `NetworkManager`. Sometimes getting data from server may takes long time.

Code will be like this

```
class NetworkManager {
    func parseJSON(completion: @escaping(_ companyModel: CompanyModel?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/1d1cb4ec-73db-4762-8c4b-0b8aa3cecd4c") else { return }

        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let companyModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(CompanyModel.self, from: jsonData)

            // return data parse from server
            completion(companyModel)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    private var companyModel: CompanyModel?
    private lazy var employeesTable: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return table
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(employeesTable)
        employeesTable.frame = view.bounds
        employeesTable.delegate = self
        employeesTable.dataSource = self
        
        // add this line
        self.initTableViewData()
    }

    func initTableViewData() {
        networkManager.parseJSON(completion: {
            companyModel in
            self.companyModel = companyModel
            self.employeesTable.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```